# Divs side by side while only partially visible

Tags: css

I want to have some div's side by side in a horizontal row.  I want the container to only show part of the row at a time with scrolling.  Currently, the div's are just in 1 column.  Maybe I'm crazy, can't see why this won't work. Thanks!

See this JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/42kurwtp/

HTML

```
    <div style="width: 300px; height: 300px; overflow:scroll;">
        <div id="blue"></div>
        <div id="red"></div>
        <div id="green"></div>
        <div id="yellow"></div>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
<style>
div {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    float: left;
}
    #blue {
        background: blue;
    }

    #red {
        background: red;
    }

    #green {
        background: green;

    }

    #yellow {
        background: yellow;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Can you explain in more details what is it that you want to happen? The colored divs go to new lines because more than one colored div cannot fit into 300px.

Comment: I guess this is what you want? http://jsfiddle.net/42kurwtp/1/

Comment: Alternatively, without adding extra markup just add `white-space: nowrap` and use `display: inline-block` instead of float: http://jsfiddle.net/00ntamn3/

Answer (score 0):

```css
<style> #row {
  overflow: scroll;
  width: 900px;
  height: 70px;
}
#row div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  float: left;
}
#blue {
  background: blue;
}
#red {
  background: red;
}
#green {
  background: green;
}
#yellow {
  background: yellow;
}
</style>
```

```html
<div class="row" id="row">
  <div id="blue">&nbsp;</div>
  <div id="red">&nbsp;</div>
  <div id="green">&nbsp;</div>
  <div id="yellow">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```