# Prevent float elements to return to the next line

Tags: html, css

I have this HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
    </div>
        <div class="row">
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
    </div>
        <div class="row">
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to prevent the items contains in the rows to return to the line.

Here's the CSS:

```
.container {
    width: 500px;
    overflow: auto;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}

.container .row:after {
    content:"";
    display:table;
    clear:both;
}

.row .item {
    float: left;
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
    border: 1px solid #f00;
}
```

I tried to change float elements to inline-block and nowrap, but I have the issue with spaces between rows. I use React, so I don't know how to remove spaces in the code, or insert comments between `<div/>`.

Here's a JSFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/Cronos87/69aoghaq/

Comment: Could you create a `jsFiddle` to reproduce the issue?

Comment: You may use and like Emmet, but not everyone uses it. Please paste the generated HTML, or at least a portion of it.

Comment: does the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30222446/divs-side-by-side-while-only-partially-visible) help you with your problem? (setting `white-space: nowrap` and `display: inline-block`?)

Comment: @MelanciaUK I just edited my post with a link to jsfiddle.

Comment: @Ben Philipp It solve my problem but create a new one. Take a look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/Cronos87/Ldgwmv9e/ I want to remove spaces but like I said, I use React and I don't know how to use famous tricks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### You can mimic a table within a container

For superior cross-browser compatibility, you can make your rows and items behave like a native table within a container.

**Update:** By setting a `min-width` on the items, you can force each table-like row to expand past the container producing a scroll bar if necessary.

```css
.container {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    width: 100px;
    overflow: auto;
}

.container .row {
    display: table;
}

.container .item {
    display: table-cell;
    min-width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
    border: 1px solid #f00;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The problem is if I use a display table, maybe I'm wrong, the rows can't have a superior width than my container. For example: if my container have a width of 100px, my four items have to fit the 100px width. I don't know if I explain well my problem...

Comment: @Cronos87 You didn't specify in your original post that allowing overflow was a requirement.

Comment: If you just want the four items to fit the width, remove the width from the `.item` rule and add it to the `.container` rule: `.contianer { width: 100px; }`

Comment: @Cronos87 what is your goal? Do you want the row items to shrink to fit the container width? Do you want the row items to expand past the container width with a scrollbar? Or something else?

Comment: Your second proposition. I'm sorry if I expressed myself badly.

Comment: @Cronos87 I've updated the example so that each `.row` is its own table and `.container` acts as a container with optional overflow. Use `min-width` to force the items to expand the "table" past the width of the container.

Answer (score 2):

You can use flexbox:

```css
.container {
  width: 100px;
  overflow: auto;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
.row {
  display: flex; /* Magic begins */
}
.row > .item {
  flex-shrink: 0; /* Don't shrink them */
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  border: 1px solid #f00;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```